# Admob ads not showing after package name changed

Tags: android-studio, admob

I am developing a new release for my app with a test package name so i don't annoy current users.

Admob's native ads were showing but once i changed the app package name to the current P.N. that i use in Play Store , ads aren't showing any more and i get this error message :

`the previous native ad failed to load. attempting to load another`

PS : ads are not restricted for my app 
**PS 2 : admob is linked to my firebase account**

**My dependencies :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' // Crash when updating
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'          // circle image view

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation "com.leinardi.android:speed-dial:2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'


    // Firebase login
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.1'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'          // Firebase Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta02'
    // Add the Firebase SDK for Crashlytics.
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.5'                 // Add the dependency for the Performance Monitoring library


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.3'          // Other Firebase
    implementation 'com.github.guy-4444:SmartRateUsDialog-Android:1.00.08' // Rate us

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'        // ads
    implementation project(':nativetemplates')                              // nativetemplates

}
```

**My gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta03'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to register the app as a fresh one and change Ids too

Comment: Could you explain more please , btw i am using a package name that is associated to an existing app on playstore

Comment: You just need to create new fresh app on AdMob. and then replace it new ads id with old one.

Comment: While create new app do not select option of select app from play store.

Comment: But test ads aren't loading too , and i think that doesn't explain it